# Printing 'box' in array

Tags: c, arrays, function

So I am facing hair loss day by day because of this sub-task required for my first year assignment.

I need to print a '**box**' around the number at coordinate [5][5] / i.e **center of the board** during the **initialization** stage of the program.

The 'box' consists of "**|**" covering the sides and "**_**" on top and bottom of the number at **coordinate [5][5]**.

When I execute this program, the board shows but the '**box**' doesn't. **Why is this happening??**

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//FUNCTION: Draw the Board
int drawBoard()
{
    //Declare array size
    int board[9][9];

    //initialize variables
    int rows, columns, randomNumber, flag;

    //random number seed generator
    srand(time(NULL));

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 9 ; rows++ )
        {

            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 9 ; columns++ )
            {
                flag = 0;

                do
               {
                    //generate random numbers from 2 - 8

                    randomNumber = rand() %7 + 2;

                    board[rows][columns] = randomNumber;

                        //Display the 'box' if rows and columns == 5 / i.e - board[5][5]
                        if ( rows == 5 && columns == 5 )
                        {   //Checks for 2 adjacent numbers
                            if  ( board[rows][columns] == board[rows - 1][columns] || board[rows][columns] == board[rows][columns - 1] )
                            {
                                flag = 0;
                                continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                flag = 1;

                                //Print 'box'
                                marker( rows, columns );
                            }
                        }

                    //Checks for 2 adjacent numbers.
                    if  ( board[rows][columns] == board[rows - 1][columns] || board[rows][columns] == board[rows][columns - 1] )
                        {
                            flag = 0;
                            continue;
                        }

                    else
                    //Prints the correct board
                         {
                                flag = 1;
                                printf( "  %d  ", board[rows][columns] );
                         }

                } while ( flag == 0 ); //end outer do-while

            }//end inner for-loop

            printf("\n\n");

        }//end outer for-loop

}//end FUNCTION drawBoard

//FUNCTION: Mark the surrounding of the number with "|" and "_" at board[5][5]
void marker( int x, int y, int** board )
  {
    board[x][y-1] == "\n _ ";
    board[x][y+1] == "\n _ ";
    board[x-1][y] == " |";
    board[x+1][y] == "| ";
  }

int main()
{
    drawBoard();
}
```

TI

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger? Making sure that `marker` gets called?

Comment: Because board is of type int?

Comment: are the numbers in the board from the range [0,9] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//FUNCTION: Draw the Board
char tochar(int i)
{
    return i+'0';
}
void marker( int x, int y, char board[][19] );
int check(int x, int y, char board[][19])
{
    if(x>1&&board[2*x+1][2*y+1]==board[2*x-1][2*y+1])
        return 1;

    if(y>1&&board[2*x+1][2*y+1]==board[2*x+1][2*y-1])
        return 1;
   return 0;
}
int drawBoard()
{
    //Declare array size
    char board[19][19];

    memset(board,32, sizeof(board));
    //initialize variables
    int rows, columns, randomNumber, flag;

    //random number seed generator
    srand(time(NULL));

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 9 ; rows++ )
        {

            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 9 ; columns++ )
            {
                flag = 0;

                do
               {
                    //generate random numbers from 2 - 8

                    randomNumber = rand() %7 + 2;
                    board[2*rows+1][2*columns+1] = tochar(randomNumber);

                        //Display the 'box' if rows and columns == 5 / i.e - board[5][5]
                        if ( rows == 4 && columns == 4 )
                        {   //Checks for 2 adjacent numbers
                            if  ( check(rows, columns, board))
                            {
                                flag = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                flag = 1;

                                marker( 2*rows+1, 2*columns+1, board );
                                //Print 'box'
                            }
                        }
                    else
                    {
                    //Checks for 2 adjacent numbers.
                    if  ( check(rows, columns, board))
                        {
                            flag = 0;
                        }

                    else
                    //Prints the correct board
                         {
                            flag = 1;
//                            printf( "  %c  ", board[2*rows+1][2*columns+1] );
                         }
                    }
                } while ( flag == 0 ); //end outer do-while

            }//end inner for-loop

            printf("\n\n");

        }//end outer for-loop
    for(rows=0;rows<19;rows++)
    {
        for(columns=0;columns<19;columns++)
        {
            printf("%c",board[rows][columns]); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}//end FUNCTION drawBoard

//FUNCTION: Mark the surrounding of the number with "|" and "_" at board[5][5]
void marker( int x, int y, char board[][19] )
  {
    board[x][y-1] = '|';
    board[x][y+1] = '|';
    board[x-1][y] = '_';
    board[x+1][y] = '_';
   /* 
192
191
217
218
*/
  }

int main()
{
    drawBoard();
}
```

Comment: Hi @titus, the program works fine. But you may have predicted it already that there a lot of question marks in my head even when I tried to analyze it. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: well ask and I'll try to explain, I had to go and didn't have time to add any explanations

Comment: I think I'll try to ask and absorb little by little to avoid information overload. To start off can you explain why has the array size is readjust to [19][19] instead of the intended [9][9]?

Comment: so you can add the characters | - in the matrix. If you have [9][9] sized matrix of int or char you can only put a number at [i][j] but you can't add a | or - easily.

Comment: oh basically the extra arrays are "spaces" in the board to contain "|" and "-"? Wow I would have never thought of that. How about char board[][19] in both functions marker() and check()? Why is it empty? and the other is [19]?

Comment: I don't really know why, it's just that you need to specify a number for the last dimension. I'm not sure if you need to specify [][19][19] or [][][19] if it was a 3D array. [][19] means that you can send [2][19] or [9999][19]. the last dimension is fixed

Comment: Oh I see! I tested out by placing [19][19] and it seems to provide similar results. The next thing I want to ask is why 2*Rows+1? Is this because of the array size that has been readjust to 19x19?

Comment: the elements in the [19][19] array start at 0 and end at 18. I chose the element positions to be at 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 (on both rows and columns) Every element can be bounded by a box this way. 1 can have a box at 0,2; 17 can have the box at 16,18; when you have rows/columns in the set {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} you multiply by 2 and add 1 to map it to {1,3,5,7, ..., 17}

Comment: how about the data_type for board? why is it char instead of int?

Comment: you need to store numbers from 1 to 9 and `'-'` and `'|'`. It's easier to store it to `char` than `int` because there is less to handle. If you would store to an `int` array, you would need to take care when printing the `'-'` and `'|'` so it doesn't print garbage.

Comment: could you explain the char tochar(int i)? I don't understand how return i+'0'; works

Comment: the '0' character has ascii value 48; google ascii table; if you look in the table '1' has value 49; to compute '1' from '0' you just add 1; so '1'=='0'+1; and so on to compute '2' you add 2 to '0'

Comment: so randomNumber is passed as int i. randomNumber + '0'?? I don't understand what does this do :/ Please do explain

Comment: randomNumbers has one of the values {2,3,...,8} tochar of randomNumbers will have {'2','3',...,'8'} (they are characters)

Answer (score 0):

```
void marker( int x, int y, int** board )
  {
    board[x][y-1] == "\n _ ";
    board[x][y+1] == "\n _ ";
    board[x-1][y] == " |";
    board[x+1][y] == "| ";
  }
```

This won't work. The '==' is for comparing, not assigning. You need a '='.
However, board is an array of int, you can't assign a `const char*` (because that's what `"something"` is) in an array of int. Your board should be an array of char, and then you can assign like this:

```
void marker( int x, int y, char** board )
  {
    board[x][y-1] = '_';
    board[x][y+1] = '_';
    board[x-1][y] = '|';
    board[x+1][y] = '|';
  }
```

Another problem is that the center of the board is at index [4][4], the fifth element of a table of size 9. But that is a smaller problem...

Answer (score 0):

I see what you want to do here, this isn't the way I usually think, so I may be not helpfull :s

first, a mistake:
in `"drawboard": marker( rows, columns )`

prototype of `"marker": void marker( int x, int y, int** board )`. I don't think compilation with flag will work (and yes, flags ARE helpfull, try `"gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror"`)

Moreover, I think you should re-think your function "marker", it can't work.

I think `board[x][y-1] = "\n _ "` would do the trick, if you `return(board[x][y-1])` but again, I would have work with a `char**`, not an integer tab,  and with many short functions (and used `write` instead of `printf` :p)